# Android mp3 playback and error (1, -19)

Tags: android

I am at my wits end with Android MediaPlayer and have scoured the web looking for help. I have an app that simply plays .mp3 files stored in the assets directory. This is the code I am executing (on Samsung Galaxy Note 4):

```
    mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("achievement.mp3");
        mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer2.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
```

The file will not playback but instead gives me the following:

```
11-26 20:55:18.824 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
11-26 20:55:18.824 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: invoke 68
11-26 20:55:18.834 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: getAudioStreamType
11-26 20:55:18.834 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getAudioStreamType: 3 (streamtype)
11-26 20:55:18.834 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
11-26 20:55:18.834 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: start
11-26 20:55:18.834 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-26 20:55:18.874 23555-23567/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-19
11-26 20:55:18.874 23555-23567/com.brainglove.iflbasic E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
11-26 20:55:18.874 23555-23567/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: callback application
11-26 20:55:18.874 23555-23567/com.brainglove.iflbasic V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
11-26 20:55:18.954 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
11-26 20:55:18.964 23555-23555/com.brainglove.iflbasic E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

I have tried putting files in raw and launching from there. No dice. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have. This occurs the moment you do mp.start(). I am creating the player at the top of the function and it is failing on first run. So to my knowledge there should be no other players instantiated or running.

Comment: Does anyone know what the -19 means? I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: BTW, I have discovered so far this is only an issue on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running 6.0.1. Other devices I have tested on play fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
    {  
        mp.stop();
    } 
    try {
        mp.reset();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: No dice, the code above resulted in an additional error:
11-27 09:02:03.618 5459-5459/com.brainglove.iflbasic E/MediaPlayer: invoke failed: wrong state 0